# Perform left mouse click from Background

Tags: c#

I have desktop app that is in background. I later want to try this a a service too.

How can I perform mouse click when certain time and date is reached.

I don't want to move user mouse or something. Just send left mouse click from background.

Comment: Background of what?  A service does not have a gui.

Comment: Surely a mouse click is not all you want to happen at a certain date and time.  Why not do the thing/write the code that happens when the mouse is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Controling an application via simulated Mouse or Keyboard input goes into the Area of Desktop Automation. There are many existing solutions for it. I advise agaisnt making your own custom hack.

That asumes you do not have control over the target application of course. If that was the case, using a Timer is the obvious way.

As for doing this from a Service: That is nigh impossible. Ever since Windows Vista, Service do not get [interactive Sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by default.This is a rather important part of the UAC security. While getting around it is possible it will propably raise some red flags.